# Clock Problem of logic

Tags: puzzle

There is an analog clock that runs 90% of the normal speed of a clock.This clock will show the correct time exactly two times a day. Prove the following.

Comment: do you mean "prove the preceding"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. Also your actual question is unclear as to what your variables are. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I am missing something, even if the clocks start synchronised, I don't see how they can show the same time again in the next $24$ hours.

The "bad" clock has to lose $12$ hours w.r.t. good one for the two to show the same time again.

Measuring by correct clock time,
In $10$ minutes, it loses $1$ minute.
In $10$ hours, it loses $1$ hour

To lose $12$ hours, it need $120$ hours of correct clock time $= 5\; days$

Answer (score 0):

Without further information the claim is not true.  Let the clock show $11:59$ when the correct time is $12:00$.  The clock will only show the correct time once in the next $24$ hours.